Ibus-avro is not working in Ubuntu 24.04 in LibreOffice
Yesterday my PC has been upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04. Earlier there was no problem for using Avro Phonetic in Libre.  But after upgradation I cannot type bengali through Avro Phonetic in Libre Writer, though iBus has been installed. However, there is no problem while typing bengali with Avro Phonetic in browser or in Text Editor.
How to fix it?

Try installing libreoffice as deb package instead of snap. sudo snap remove libreoffice and sudo apt install libreoffice. Does Avro work now?

@ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks for your reply. I will let you know on Monday as I have already left my workplace.

Ubuntu 24.04 uses a different version of Libreoffice than 22.04.  In my situation, I cannot use the version of libreoffice found in 24.04 due to a yet unresolved bug.

@ArchismanPanigrahi What you have suggested didn't work. Therefore, I have deleted the Libreoffice which was earlier downloaded from snap. Then I installed LibreOffice from Ubuntu Repository and now it is possible to write Bengali through Avro. I think there is a bug in the latest version of LibreOffice.

The command I suggested does exactly that. It removes snap libreoffice, and installs it from the APT repo. The issue is snap, not the latest version of libreoffice

@quill Please ask a new question

@Archisman Panigrahi What question should I be asking?

In my situation, I cannot use the version of libreoffice found in 24.04 due to a yet unresolved bug. - You describe what the issue is, and ask for solution (unless it is already reported as a bug)

@Archisman Panigrahi.  Should I ask a question for something which I already know the answer to? LO bug 154975 blocks use of letter or legal size paper in any printer able to handle larger paper (such as tabloid size) because letter or legal size output will be always rotated.  This was introduced in LO 7.5.0.  Ubuntu 24 picked up a later version which has this bug.  I get around the problem with a manual install of a previous version. Since I know the issue and a long term work around, is it appropriate to ask a question and immediately provide the answer?

@quill Yes, it is appropriate, and will help other users in future

New question, and answer created.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525295/libreoffice-printing-is-always-in-landscape-format/1525296#1525296

This seems to be an issue of the snap app sandboxing.
Remove the snap libreoffice.
sudo snap remove libreoffice

Now, install it from the official Ubuntu repositories
sudo apt install libreoffice

If you want to install the latest version of Libreoffice (without snap), add the Libreoffice Fresh PPA
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall libreoffice

